# Can I remove policy kit?

Tags: policykit

On every desktop startup, I have a dialog asking for password. The cause is policy kit.

I haven't found what *exactly* is raising the prompt, but it brings me to the question:

**Do I need policy kit? If so, why?**

If not, how do I remove it?

```
sudo apt remove polkit*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'polkit-1-auth-agent' for glob 'polkit*'
Note, selecting 'polkit-kde-agent-1' for glob 'polkit*'
Package 'polkit-kde-agent-1' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
sudo apt remove polkit-1-auth-agent
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'polkit-1-auth-agent' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Don't- you'll break your system. Policy kit is the inherent security of the linux system. Don't remove part of your system (same for python and many others)

Comment: Right. I just tried it with a VM! Boom. 
Thanks. Any idea how to track down what is causing policy kit to ask for password when my desktop starts up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

polkit (formerly Policy Kit) provides two important services.

From the [project documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html):

> an authorization API intended to be used by privileged programs (“MECHANISMS”) offering service to unprivileged programs (“SUBJECTS”) often through some form of inter-process communication mechanism.

...and...

> allows users to obtain temporary authorization through authenticating either an administrative user or the owner of the session the client belongs to.

The first provides a safe way for user-level applications to ask for root-level actions. You might use this regularly without noticing in Desktop systems -- like suspending, or mounting newly-inserted hardware. Polkit is part of that mysterious glue that makes the desktop work.

The second is (most commonly) the GUI "*admin privileges are required for this actions*" dialog.

---

polkit is a necessary element in all Ubuntu Desktop (GUI) systems. Removing polkit will destroy your Ubuntu Desktop (GUI) system. It's generally not needed if you run headless (without GUI / Ubuntu Server), though folks do sometimes add software that needs polkit.

Comment: Are you sure this causes errors on server?  A lot of my systems installed with ubuntu server never had polkit installed, and I haven't removed it.  (Note: I fully agree that polkit is needed for desktop -- even desktop installed on server.)

Comment: @user10489 The phrase used in the answer is "...and **may** cause..." Some people do strange stuff with servers. Many users, like you, do not encounter any problems.

Comment: in all Ubuntu **Desktop** systems. It's not needed if you run headless.

Comment: Note that the package `network-manager` depends by the package `polkitd`. So, probably you may want to keep it.